# How can i write a string/query to a hive query file in cmd?

Tags: cmd, hive, cloudera

i have ran the below so i can write this to a file settings.hql

```
"SET schema = products;SET company = amazon;SET tablename = test;" > settings.hql
```

in cmd.

but it does not work i get:

```
 SET schema = products;SET company = amazon;SET tablename = test;: command not found
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `echo` command:

```
C:\Users\leftjoin>echo SET schema = products;SETcompany = amazon;SET tablename = test; > settings.hql

C:\Users\leftjoin>type settings.hql
SET schema = products;SETcompany = amazon;SET tablename = test;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Microsoft Windows `cmd.exe` as your tag implies, you need to use `ECHO`.

```
ECHO>"settings.hql" SET schema = products;SET company = amazon;SET tablename = test;
```